# Octave socket close

Tags: sockets, octave

I'm trying to use Octave to open a simple socket server.  While debugging, my script crashed after it had bound to a port.  Of course, subsequent binds to the same port now fail.  How can I close the socket so that I can reuse the port?  Right now all I can do is close active entirely, which kills the process that is running the listener.

Ric

Comment: You need to set SO_REUSEADDR on the socket before binding. Don't ask me how you do that in Octave. You will need to exit the process and wait a couple of minutes to get rid of this particular socket.

Comment: Exactly this was the reason I made a fork https://github.com/octave-de/octave-sockets-enh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this from happening in the future, you can use [`onCleanup`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/onCleanup.html) or [`unwind_protect`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/The-unwind_005fprotect-Statement.html) to ensure that the socket-closing code always happens, even if your script errors out unexpectedly.